# Minimum number of hamilton cycles in a 4-connected planar triangulation?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-graphs

I am currently interested in hamilton cycles (i.e. a cycle through every vertex) in planar triangulations (i.e. planar graphs with every face a triangle).

There are non-hamiltonian planar triangulations about which I have nothing to say or ask. However if a planar triangulation is hamiltonian then it has at least 4 hamilton cycles, and Hakimi, Schmeichel and Thomassen (HST) found an infinite family of planar triangulations with *exactly* 4 hamilton cycles. However the only infinite families of planar triangulations with a bounded number of hamilton cycles have *separating triangles* (i.e. 3-vertex clique-cutsets) and can in some sense be viewed as "reducible'' configurations.

Therefore HST asked what is the smallest number of hamilton cycles that a *$4$-connected* planar triangulation on $n$ vertices can have, and conjectured that the answer is $2(n-2)(n-4)$ hamilton cycles. Furthermore they conjectured that the unique example realising this is the complete join of $2K_1$ (two isolated vertices) to a cycle of length $n-2$.

My question is whether this has been proved or any progress has been made on it. I have searched fairly hard through MathSciNet and Google, and have convinced myself that there are no small counterexamples.

Comment: True up to 16 vertices...

Comment: @Brendan -  I've done all I could do with plantri in an afternoon... it looks very solid, but can't think of how to play prove!

Comment: Can you provide a link to HST paper?

Comment: Ilya, the paper is here: http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/jgt.3190030407. (However for me it is behind a paywall, and I had to actually physically walk to our library to look at it.)